# CollectionView with SelectionChanged and TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView with a Grid inside it. When I select an element, through the TapGestureRecognizer event I set the background of the Grid to Transparent. The problem is that the application no longer enters the SelectionChanged event it normally entered when making a selection. is it possible to enable them both?

**This is my XAML code:**

```
<CollectionView               
            x:Name="CategoryView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding list}" 
            Margin="10,0,10,0"
            SelectionMode="Multiple"               
            SelectionChanged="CategoryView_SelectionChanged">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" VerticalItemSpacing="15" HorizontalItemSpacing="3"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                        
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Titolo}" FontSize="19" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" Margin="13,0,0,0"/>
                        <!--Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Descrizione}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" Margin="13,0,0,0"/-->
                        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                        <Image Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Start" Source="checked.png" IsVisible="{Binding Vis}"  Margin="20,10,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

**This is my c# code:**

```
private void CategoryView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = e.CurrentSelection;
        
        list.Clear();
        foreach (ClassCategory cat in selected)
        {
            cat.Vis = true;
            list.Add(cat.Titolo);
        }            
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var entity = ((Grid)sender);
        entity.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `TapGestureRecognizer`, just binding the `BackgroundColor` of Grid to a property in your Viewmodel:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding myBackGroundColor}">
```

Then in the `CategoryView_SelectionChanged` method to update the `myBackGroundColor` color:

```
private void CategoryView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected = e.CurrentSelection;
        
         
        MyModel model = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyModel.
        model.myBackGroundColor = Color.Transparent;

        list.Clear();
        foreach (ClassCategory cat in selected)
        {
            cat.Vis = true;
            list.Add(cat.Titolo);
        }            
    }
```

Update:

```
class ClassCatefory : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Color backGroundColor;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ClassCatefory()
    {
    }

    public Color myBackGroundColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (backGroundColor != value)
            {
                backGroundColor = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("myBackGroundColor"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return backGroundColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'selected' is not an Object of my class, but a collection of elements

Comment: OK, it should be `e.CurrentSelection`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#single-selection) to refer.

Comment: MyModel should be my class right? I created the property 'MyBackground' of type Color and I put the color Transparent, but it doesn't change in any way the selection of the Grid

Comment: Binding MyBackground should be same as binding Titolo to label. Does the binding work?

Comment: Is that correct? [link](https://i.postimg.cc/yYbxf1fw/Immagine.png)

Comment: Yes, looks well. You should make sure the binding work first. Give the background a default value like red and see if the backgroundcolor of gird turns red when the page load.

Comment: Test Binding doesn't work either, and if I try to press the button, this exception comes out.
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' `

Comment: Does the Titolo binding work? NullReferenceException means e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault. Can you add a break point there to debug where is your model data? I don't know your data structure.

Comment: [xaml](https://i.postimg.cc/zfP820qJ/xa.png), [c#](https://i.postimg.cc/1tkPsXg2/xaml.png) [c#2](https://i.postimg.cc/XJG3Rdv9/c.png) if you can help me I am grateful. thank you so much

Comment: See my updated answer about myBackGroundColor property.

Comment: continue to be displayed in orange [image](https://ibb.co/2ND2Zp1)

Comment: You should add break point and debug if the binding work. And check whether you get the right model in the CategoryView_SelectionChanged event? It's a basic binding problem and see the example model [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm).